# Ruby - uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this 4 classes, the code is simple but when I try to generate, it returns an error like

```
in `<main>': uninitialized constant PruebasUnitarias (NameError)
```

The code is this and I dont know what is wrong, I thought it was because of requires, but I have all in one document and still crash.

```
class Complejo
  def initialize (real, imaginario)
    @real = real
    @imaginario = imaginario
  end

  def sumar (complejo)
    @real = @real + complejo.real
    @imaginario = @imaginario + complejo.imaginario
  end
  attr_reader :real, :imaginario
end

class Prueba
  def assertCierto(valor)
    return valor
  end

  def assertFalso(valor)
    return valor
  end

  def assertIgual(num1, num2)
    if(num1 == num2)
      return true
    end
    return false
  end

  def assertDistinto(num1, num2)
    if(num1 != num2)
      return true
    end
    false
  end

  def assertNil param
    if (param == nil)
      return true
    end
    false
  end

  def assertContiene(param1, param2)
    param1.include?(param2)
  end

end

class PruebasUnitarias::Prueba
  def run
    metodos = self.methods
    if(self.respond_to? :inicializacion)
      self.inicializacion
    end

  end
end

class PruebaComplejo < PruebasUnitarias::Prueba
  def inicializacion
    @c1 = Complejo.new(3,5)
    @c2 = Complejo.new(1,-1)
  end

  def prueba_suma
    @c1.sumar(@c2)
    assertIgual(@c1.real, 4)
    assertIgual(@c1.imaginario, 4)
  end

  def prueba_suma_cero
    @c2.sumar(Complejo.new(0,0))
    assertCierto(@c2.real==1)
    assertCierto(@c2.imaginario==-1)
  end

  def prueba_suma_nula
    @c2.sumar(nil)
    assertIgual(@c2.real, 1)
    assertIgual(@c2.imaginario, -1)
  end

  def imprimir (complejo)
    puts "complejo: #{complejo.real}, #{complejo.imaginario}i"
  end
end
```

Comment: The error is in this line
class PruebasUnitarias::Prueba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the module before you can put a class in it. Try this instead:

```
module PruebasUnitarias
  class Prueba
    ...
  end
end
class PruebaComplejo < PruebasUnitarias::Prueba
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you but i cant change de class declarations so PruebaComplejo must be class PruebaComplejo < PruebasUnitarias::Prueba

Answer (score 0):

Just as a note about your programming style, you need to think in simpler terms when it comes to testing your values. Consider these changes:

```
def assertCierto(valor)
  valor
end

def assertFalso(valor)
  valor
end

def assertIgual(num1, num2)
  num1 == num2
end

def assertDistinto(num1, num2)
  num1 != num2
end

def assertNil param
  param == nil
end
```

It's not necessary to use an `if` test to see if something is equal or not equal and then return `true` or `false`. The test itself does that so simply compare the values and let Ruby return the result by default.

```
1 == 1 # => true
1 == 2 # => false
1 != 1 # => false
1 != 2 # => true
```

Also, use snake_case for method names, not camelCase. ItsAReadabilityThing:

```
  def assert_cierto(valor)

  def assert_falso(valor)

  def assert_igual(num1, num2)

  def assert_distinto(num1, num2)

  def assert_nil param
```

Comment: thank you, already changed it. Its my 2nd program in Ruby, I always program in C o Java